# How to Import new categories and products from one site to another without overriding the existing

Tags: magento-1.9, import, export

I want to **export** the **categories** from **live site** and **import** into the **development site** in **Magento**.

I have followed the method to import through the default **import/export** via dataprofiles but it **overrides** the existing **categories** and **products** and their settings as well . I have **products** and **categories** on live db which I need to **import into development db without overriding** the **existing products and categories on development site**. Can anyone please help me out of it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have categories & products in your localhost also?

Comment: No,But i have backup of the whole dev site

Comment: Do your development site has some different categories & products than your live site into it

Comment: I have products and categories on live db which i need to import into development db wihout overriding the existing products and categories on development site

Comment: yes, development and live products & categories are different

Comment: It will override each other because of the conflicting Id's of categories

Comment: just look into both the sites from your backend that if two different categories or products have same ids into their individual tables?

Comment: no they have different ids in database, so they will get override right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68865/discussion-between-abhishek-tripathi-and-nikita).